# Wie nennt man ein Produkt oder eine Dienstleistung, die ein Unternehmen nur anbietet, weil es "muss"?

Tags: noun

Wie nennt man ein Produkt oder eine Dienstleistung, die ein Unternehmen nur anbietet, weil es denkt, andere erwarten dieses Angebot? Aber tatsächlich bestellt es kein Kunde, noch *möchte* das Unternehmen das Produkt bzw. die Dienstleistung vertreiben. Sollte jemand doch das Produkt bestellen wird das Unternehmen den Kunden umlenken.

Hat das im Deutschen einen Begriff?

Comment: Hast Du ein Beispiel dafür oder ist die Frage rein theoretisch?

Comment: _Feigenblatt_ wird manchmal in diese Richtung gebraucht.

Comment: Mir ist die Frage etwas unklar: Firmen bieten idR keine Produkte an sich an, weil sie erwarten, dass der Kunde erwartet, dass sie diese anböten. Stattdessen findet aber *bundling* statt, d.h. man bündelt erwünschte Produkte mit anderen aus diversen Gründen, auch weil der Kunde eine solche Kombination möglicherweise erwartet. Alternativ gibt es compliance-Produkte: Solche, die aus gesetzlichen Regulationsgründen angeboten werden. Zum Beispiel bietet BMW in Argentinien Reis an, weil sie sonst keine Autos importieren dürfen.

Comment: Mir ist die Verwendung des Wortes "umlenken" nicht klar.

Comment: Wenn niemand oder auch nur sehr wenige dieses Angebot erwarten (das Unternehmen "denkt" dies ja nur), dann ist dieses Produkt ein "Fehler".

Comment: @Carlster, vielleicht "umlenken" im Sinne von "switch" in "bait-and-switch"... Dann wäre es wohl ein ["Lockvogelangebot"](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/bait+and+switch.html).

Comment: Hat diese Frage irgendeinen Bezug [hierzu](url=http://www.spiegel.de/spam/bild-981241-725544.html)?

Comment: Es gibt den Begriff der *Katalogleiche* für Produkte, die nur da drin stehen, um das Produktportfolio "voll zu kriegen"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohne nähere Information würde ich das Ding ein **Alibiprodukt** nennen. (Analog: **Alibidienstleistung**)

Update: Nach Diskussion im Chat, und da die Antwort akzeptiert wurde, ohne auf die Kommentare einzugehen wurde, insbes. nicht auf die Bitte nach Beispielen:

Denkbar ist eine Bürokratie, die vorschreibt, dass Schnaps nur zu Desinfektionszwecken verkauft werden darf. Als Beweis genügt es, wenn immer eine Mullbinde mitverkauft wird. Das würde ich Alibiprodukt nennen. Hier würde aber niemand umgelenkt werden, sondern die Firma müsste ja Mullbinden mitverkaufen, also auch auf Lager haben. Die Firma könnte aber damit rechnen, dass niemand nur Mullbinden kauft, noch dazu im großen Stil, etwa 100 Packungen.

Anderer Fall: Ein Autoteilezubehörladen, der vor allem überteuerten Schnickschnack anbietet, alles 5x so teuer wie von der Stange, und um den Eindruck zu erwecken, dass man ein richtiger Nobelladen ist, hat man einen vergoldeten Rollce-Royce im Katalog, aber nicht im Laden oder Lager auf Vorrat. Aber denkt der Unternehmer die Kunden erwarten dieses Angebot? Passt auch nicht 100%ig, das Beispiel - so etwas würde ich eher ein **Blendprodukt** nennen.

Comment: Du kannst ruhig auch das **Alibi-Angebot** aufführen, dieser Begriff taucht wenigstens ab und an auf.

Comment: Wie genau fließt die Bedeutung von "Alibi" in diesen Begriff ein?

Comment: @Takkat: Alibiprodukt taucht auch ab und an auf, nämlich 1580 mal bei Google.

Comment: @Carlster: Synonyme für Alibi lt. Duden: Ausflucht, Ausrede, Deckmantel, Entschuldigung, Rechtfertigung, Vorwand; (veraltend) Vorgeben

Comment: Ich habe eh auch nachgesehen, bevor ich die Frage gestellt habe - welches dieser Wörter fließt nun wie ein?

Comment: @Carlster: Rechtfertigung, Deckmantel oder Vorwand fließen ein. Wie fließen sie ein? Sinnstiftend. ;)

Comment: So wie in Deckmantelprodukt/Rechtfertigungsprodukt/Vorwandsprodukt?

Comment: Ja, und so wie in Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftsvorsitzendenehegattinennkaffeekränzchen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15754/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-carlster).

Comment: +1 für die Mühe - ist echt nicht leicht.

Comment: @userunknown: "Alibiprodukt" 317 "Alibi Produkt" 457 "Alibiangebot" 704 "Alibi Angebot" 3690 - zur Suche nach isolierten Begriffen braucht Google Gänsefüßchen. "Blendprodukt" 114, aber meist in völlig anderem Kontext.

Comment: Und was sucht Google ohne Anfühungsstriche, wenn man nur ein Wort eingibt? Und was ändert die Zahl 317?

Answer (score 0):

Produkte, die zwar angeboten, aber nie nennenswert (aus welchen Gründen auch immer, einer dieser Gründe kann sein, dass der Anbieter bestimmte Vorgaben erfüllen muss, aber eigentlich mit diesen Gütern gar kein Geschäft machen *will*) in den Handel gelangen, nennt man auch

> Katalogleichen

Comment: m. E. sind Katalogleichen Produkte die man eben **doch** verkaufen will, aber nicht los wird. Der Vorsatz (zumindest hin und wieder) bewusst etwas unverkäufliches auf Lager zu haben ist bei dem Begriff denke ich nicht gegeben.

Comment: @mtwde Produkte, die man verkaufen *will* aber nicht *kann*, sind *Ladenhüter*.